# How to fix HDRI not being installed properly

Tags: hdri

Im trying to install an HDRI (https://polyhaven.com/a/mutianyu) this one

but when i tried to do it while following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VBkj_I-ONk)

this is the result I got

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: maybe switch to Perspective instead of Orthographic? Orthographic doesn't allow to correctly see the HDRI. If it doesn't fix the problem, please show your node setup

Comment: Double check you used an _Environment Texture_ node for your HDRI image and not an _Image Texture_ node.

Comment: That was the problem , I was not using an enviornment texture, thanks a lot Christopher